# Screen sharing software/service with 'feedback' functionality?

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to share my desktop with customers to demo our software. There are many services to do so like CoPilot or Skype desktop sharing. However, I'm looking for a way for the customer to use their mouse to indicate points on the screen they are talking about when they ask me something, but nothing else (e.g. not allowed to press buttons or anything). Basically I would like to see the user's cursor on my screen when it's over the remote desktop, maybe in a different color or shape than my 'regular' cursor. Does something like this exist? Thanks.

Comment: Easiest solution: ask your client to share his screen with you

Answer (score 1):

You can use TeamViewer and configure it to show the Remote Cursor. Which would allow you to see their movements on the screen and have them show you what they are talking about.

http://www.teamviewer.com